# Density or Pressure based solver CFD

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerodynamics, cfd

I’m currently trying to simulate the 2d cross section of a bullet using Ansys Fluent but am really confused about which solver type to use- density or pressure based?

Conditions:
Transonic (M=0.8)
Reynolds number 3million

I’ve been searching online and am getting really mixed reactions for this- some say that pressure is better for this Mach as it models shocks better but then some also say density solver models shockwaves better?

Comment: So run both. Which matches the results better?

Comment: Hi, I wanted some reasoning behind it, not just it runs better after trying both. Besides, I haven’t actually got any data to match to

Comment: So one of the things when using CFD is validating the results. What are you going to validate any CFD result with?

Comment: Hi, respectfully, that’s not what my question is here

Comment: Then pick one method as you won’t have any clue about the validity of the result.

Comment: Hi, I managed to get some data from my teacher, tried both and the density one is more precise, but why?